# Issue with Call Forwarding to Numbers that have are a Specific Length

Tags: twilio-twiml, forwarding

Im seeking assistance regarding an issue with call forwarding.

I have implemented call forwarding within my TwiML code to redirect incoming calls to a different phone number. The code is working as expected when forwarding calls to numbers of certain lengths, such as "+64277006667" (11 digits). However, I am facing difficulties when attempting to forward calls to numbers with a different length, such as "+642108224822 (12 digits)."

I have tested the call forwarding with various numbers, and the issue seems to persist consistently with numbers of a specific length. 11 digits and the call forwards, 12 digits and it doesnt.

This number is my number and has always worked in the past.

Below is my code:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Response> <Dial record ="record-from-answer"> <Number url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH01c4fff2df5a96f08314151622196888> +642108224822 </Number></Dial> </Response>`

Thanks!
Ronnie

Comment: What is the difficulty you are encountering? What error is shown in the Twilio Debug log?